# Error with real UR5: Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic, ur5

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I get the following error when I try to send the UR5 a goal: `Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running.`

Here are the commands I am running:

```
$ roslaunch ur_robot_driver ur5_bringup.launch robot_ip:=169.254.198.35 kinematics_config:="${HOME}/my_robot_calibration.yaml"
$ roslaunch ur5_moveit_config ur5_moveit_planning_execution.launch sim:=true
$ roslaunch ur5_moveit_config moveit_rviz.launch config:=true
```

The console is however printing that the controllers have been loaded:

```
[INFO] [1574671438.720679]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
[INFO] [1574671438.728787]: Started controllers: joint_state_controller, scaled_pos_traj_controller, speed_scaling_state_controller, force_torque_sensor_controller
```

RViz is still able to plan the goal. Does anyone know what the issue is? Let me know if more information is needed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338484/error-with-real-ur5:-can%27t-accept-new-action-goals.-controller-is-not-running./) by [shu](https://answers.ros.org/users/49514/shu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 64 on 2019-11-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running.

The "controller" here is most likely the `JointTrajectoryController` (see [here](https://github.com/ros-controls/ros_controllers/blob/9bb2657b96a4ff0a1f6350f899adbf107548d313/joint_trajectory_controller/include/joint_trajectory_controller/joint_trajectory_controller_impl.h#L587) where it prints that message). Even though the spawner has tried to start it, it may not actually be running, probably due to the robot controller (ie: the UR controller) not being in the correct state.

Make sure you have a TP program running that starts the *External Control* mode.

See [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#4](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/issues/4) for an issue about the exact same problem.

There is an open PR to add a FAQ section to the `ur_robot_driver` documentation which also describes this: [UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver#44](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/pull/44/files).

Finally: *always* copy-paste verbatim console output into your question. It's very difficult to help you if you paraphrase errors or don't show context.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-11-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1